# Cuba-Platform: sample-user-registration-master HSQLDB connection error: OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: cuba-platform

I like to use the user registration demo. I just cloned the project and compiled and started it, just out of the box. the following error occured:

'''HSQLDB connection error
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: connection exception: connection failure: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
connection exception: connection failure: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this exception happens when port 9010 used by HSQL by default is occupied by another application (don't ask how occupied port is connected to "outofmemory", no idea).

As a workaround, you can change HSQLDB connection port in the main data store settings.

More discussion here:
https://www.cuba-platform.com/discuss/t/hsqldb-connection-error-outofmemory/13294/7